# HasOne and belongsTo relationships in the same model sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize along with nodejs and am having difficulties with a relationship.

I have 3 tables where (local, equipment, shed, area) where in one place I have 1 equipment, it is in a shed and belongs to an area.

The models look like this:

local:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('local', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idEquipment: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idShed: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    situation: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    capacity: {
        type: dataTypes.FLOAT,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posX: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posY: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    posZ: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.belongsTo(models.area, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.belongsTo(models.equipment, {
        foreignKey: 'idEquipment'
    });

    // model.belongsTo(models.shed, {
    //     foreignKey: 'idShed'
    // });
};

return model;

};[]
```

equipment:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('equipment', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idHangar: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    dateControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    idUserControlPlan: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: true,
        required: false
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.hasOne(models.local, {
        foreignKey: 'idEquipment'
    });
};

return model;
};
```

shed:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('shed', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    idArea: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    // model.hasOne(models.local, {
    //     foreignKey: 'idShed'
    // });

    model.belongsTo(models.area, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });
};

return model;

};
```

area:

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
const model = sequelize.define('area', {
    id: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING(200),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: dataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: dataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: true
    }
}).schema('public');

model.associate = (models) => {
    model.belongsToMany(models.company, {
        through: 'companyArea',
        foreignKeyConstraint: true,
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.hasOne(models.shed, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });

    model.hasOne(models.local, {
        foreignKey: 'idArea'
    });
};

return model;

};
```

When I add the shed relationship, it informs me that there is no relationship, when shooting everything will normally:

> [SQL Error] SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "public.sheds" does not exist EXIT
>   [SQL Error] relation "public.sheds" does not exist EXIT

I am using postgres database.

Where could that be the mistake, would it be a writing error? Or a template can not have a belongsTo and hasOne relationship at the same time?

Comment: I'm happy to help, though I'm having trouble understanding your relationships. Would you be able to simplify the relationships (e.g. maybe just use two tables) and re-create your problem?

Comment: In fact this relationship is very complex, the point is that the place has an area, is in a shed and has 1 equipment. so I have 3 1:1 relationship

Comment: Would the sync of the sequelize, would it be asynchronous?